# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_imap.dll

Tags: php, linux

i got an error like

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_imap.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_imap.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[Mon Aug 20 17:56:35 2018] Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8000 (reason: Address already in use)
```

I tried and comment out `extension=php_imap.dll` from php.ini.but bad luck still the error.How can i solve the issue?Any help would be appreciated

Comment: check this link https://askubuntu.com/questions/776322/startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-usr-lib-php-20151012-php-mbstring-dll

Comment: Have you checked both `php.ini` ? There usually are one for CLI and one for your web server

Comment: Your directory structure suggests you are using a linux but a `dll` is used on Windows and not Linux. Did you make a typo as I would expect the imap to be `php_imap.so`. Or did you install a windows extension of a Linux system??

Comment: 2) If you amended the `php.ini` and it had no effect then did you amend the correct `php.ini` there are sometimes 2, one for PHP CLI and the other for PHP under Apache. AND did you restart Apache after amending the `php.ini`

Comment: @RiggsFolly yep i restarted apache.but still same

Comment: @RiggsFolly i have change php.ini under apache

Comment: Then run a script with just `<?php phpinfo();?>` in it and look at the `php.ini` file location being used by your apache. Its called `Loaded Configuration File` and is on the first page of the output. Is that the `php.ini` file you edited

Comment: Are you using Linux/Unix or Windows as an OS

Comment: @RiggsFolly linux mint

Comment: Then using a DLL file wont work, unless there is something special about mint. So where did you get that extension from? Is the actual extension called `php_imap.dll` or `php_imap.so` which is more a Linux naming convension

Comment: @RiggsFolly when i run php artisan serve i got the error message

Comment: `Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8000 (reason: Address already in use)` make sure you only start the server once !!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `sudo apt-get install php-imap`. That should fix your it.

If that doesn't work, try this:

Go to your php.ini file, look for php_imap.dll and comment it out. Your .ini file should be in `/etc/php/your-php-version/cli/php.ini` and `/etc/php/your-php-version/apache/php.ini`. Comment out the said line by adding semi-colon before it like so `;extension=php_imap.dll`. Then restart apache by doing so `sudo service apache2 restart`